# what is the difference between hostname and servicename?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

To let other service / system / docker container talk to my container, should I give them docker service name or i must define hostname?

here is the sample docker compose file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  test:
services:
  testservicename:
    networks: 
      - test
    image: test.thedevcloud.net:8000/test/app:1.2
    container_name: testcontainername
    hostname: testhostname
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hostname only affects the internal hostname within your container, the container name/service name itself can be used to connect to your service from other applications and is the actual DNS hostname.

So the hostname only affects the 'inside' of your container and changes nothing about the networking or connection options.